# Как записать PHP код в файл, но не выполнять его при записи

Tags: php

Записываю (кэширую) небольшое кол-во товаров (хитов) в файл при помощи функции:

`file_put_contents($file, serialize($content))`.

При записи присутствуют `HTML` код и сам `PHP` код в небольшом количестве.
Цена для товара выводится так: `<?=$hit->price;?>`. Соответственно этот код надо выполнить при записи, что сейчас и происходит, но в начале записываемой информации в файл, присутствует строка:

```
<?php $currency = \system\App::$result->get('currency'); ?>
```

и в самом файле уже вывод значения: `<?=$currency['value'];?>`

`$currency` - это массив с активной валютой на сайте. Получается, если этот код отработает при записи файла, что сейчас и происходит, то при смене валюты,

`<?=$currency ['value'];?>` - уже не отработает, т.к. эта строчка кода уже отработала при записи.

Как можно записать и не выполнять при записи эти строчки кода?:

```
 <?php $currency = \system\App::$result->get('currency'); ?>
 <?=$currency['value'];?>
```

соответственно, когда будет подключаться готовый кэшированный файлик при обновлении страницы, будут выполняться эти строки кода каждый раз.

Может кто знает. Возникает идея, обрамления нужного `PHP` кода, но как не знаю и поможет ли это вообще тоже не знаю:)

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php if(isset($data['hits'])): ?>
   <?php $currency = \system\App::$result->get('currency'); ?>
   <div class="section-product-hits">
      <?php foreach($data['hits'] as $hit): ?>
         <div class="product-price">
            <?php if(!$hit['discount_price']): ?>
               <span class="price">
                  <?=$currency['symbol_left'];?> <?=$hit->price / $currency['value'];?>
               </span>
            <?php else: ?>
               <?=$currency['symbol_left'];?> <span class="price"><?=$hit->discount_price / $currency['value'];?></span> 
               <?=$currency['symbol_left'];?> <span class="old-price"><?=$hit->price / $currency['value'];?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
         </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: можно глянуть сорс?
Скорее всего вам нужно просто где-то кавычки добавить/убрать

Comment: @ДмитрийШевчук, Добрый вечер. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: с кодом  $currency = \system\App::$result->get('currency');  всё понятно, а что должно записывать вместо  $currency['value']?

Comment: @ДмитрийШевчук,Туда попадает текущий курс выбранной валюты на сайте.

Comment: Вот и хотелось бы, чтобы `$currency['value']` тоже не срабатывала, как код php при записи, а срабатывала уже из готового кэшированного файла:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($data[hits])): ?>
   <?php $currency = \system\App::$result->get("currency"); ?>
<?php ob_start() ?>
   <div class="section-product-hits">
      <?php foreach($data[hits] as $hit): ?>
         <div class="product-price">
            <?php if(!$hit[discount_price]): ?>
               <span class="price">
                  <?=$currency[symbol_left];?> <?='<?=$hit->price / $currency[value];?>'?>
               </span>
            <?php else: ?>
               <?=$currency[symbol_left];?> <span class="price"><?=$hit->discount_price / $currency[value];?></span> 
               <?=$currency[symbol_left];?> <span class="old-price"><?=$hit->price / $currency[value];?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
         </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
<?php 
$content = ob_get_flush();
file_put_contents($file, $content).
?>
<?php endif; ?>';
```

В комментарии не влезало, пихну в ответ)

Comment: Спасибо!
Но, к сожалению, данный вариант не сработает. Я написал различные виджеты. При загрузке сайта, собираются эти виджеты для той страницы, куда обратились и уже готовый вид страницы кэшируется, чтобы при следующем обновлении страницы не лезть в базу данных и снова брать от туда данные для виджетей. Поэтому этот файл с кодом из моего вопроса по сути прошел уже через мой класс кэша, где и находится `file_put_contents($file, serialize($content))`.

Comment: Кэширую файл с расширением `.php`.